# Trouble installing Kivy on pyCharm

Tags: pycharm, installation, kivy

I can't install Kivy on pycharm, it doesn't seem to recognize it

I followed the instructions on the kivy website for the installation, which was completed.

I tried to get Kivy to work on pyCharm: I followed these instructions: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's
I only have the basic python interpreter to choose from, but I also tried to install the Kivy package, which didn't seem to make a difference (File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter > +(Available packages) and selected Kivy)

I tried following different online tutorials, which all seemed pretty similar one to the other, but my problem persists.

This is the shown message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ivost/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Kivy try.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: That link does not look like the most helpful thing. (it only contains **kkkk**, seriously). Is it now dead? Please post links to all tutorials.

Comment: Can you run your code successfully without using PyCharm?

Comment: No I can't run it outside of PyCharm either (in the IDLE)

This is the main tutorial I used to install it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be anything special to install in Pycharm as far as modules are concerned. Pycharm scans your Python installation. So when you install a new package with pip, it will automatically be available in Pycharm. Assuming you don't have several python installation and are confused as to which one gets the installation though...

The tutorial page you mention will help you with other things, like code coloring/completion with kv language for instance but is not necessary if you just need to write kivy apps in Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble installing Kivy too.
It only worked when I uninstalled and reinstalled Kivy from Terminal.
To uninstall:

```
    $ pip uninstall kivy
```

To install:

```
    $ python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown because you haven't installed the dependancies foe kivy,for that, you should install these three modules in the projects interpreter settings as well after installing kivy:

```
kivy-deps.sdl2
kivy-deps.glew
kivy-deps.gstreamer
```

it should solve the problem